# Get rid of old reviews by replacing app completely?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

Old versions of my app got bad 1 star reviews. Customers love the new versions but the old bad ratings lower the average and hurt sales.

As far as I know, the only way to get rid of those outdated ratings would be to replace the app completely and alienating current customers.

Has anybody a better idea or done a complete replacement and want to share the experience ?

Answer (score 0):

Now as per the new rules apple Allows you to control the old reviews. So as per new rules when you are submitted new version they allows if we wants to continue with the old reviews or wants to clean it up. So by this way you should get rid from the old reviews.

**Important Note :**

- Even if we do not retain the old reviews while submitting the new version it will still keep showing the average ratings which you can't control or remove

Hope this helps to everyone.